# Authenticate client call to Cloud Function in Golang using service account

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I deployed my own cloud function to GCP. On the cloud function, I enabled authenticating using Google Service Account. I need to write a Golang code to call this cloud function. I've done the same purpose with Nodejs, but can't make Golang to work.

Here is my Nodejs code (working):

```js
const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');

const targetAudience = "cloud-function-url"

async function run() {
    const auth = new GoogleAuth();

    const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
    const res = await client.request({ url });
    console.info(res.data);
}
```

My Golang code:

```golang
import  "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
func getToken() (err error) {
    scope := "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    client, err := google.DefaultClient(context.Background(), scope)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    res, err := client.Get("cloud-function-url")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
    return
}
```

I also tried to customize the code to add `targetAudience`, but it doesn't work either

```golang
baseUrl := "your-cloudfunction-baseurl"
ctx := context.Background()
targetAudience := baseUrl
credentials, err := google.FindDefaultCredentials(ctx)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("cannot get credentials: %v", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

tokenSrc, err := google.JWTAccessTokenSourceFromJSON(credentials.JSON, targetAudience)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("cannot create jwt source: %v", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

client := oauth2.NewClient(context.Background(), tokenSrc)
if err != nil {
    return
}
res, err := client.Get(baseUrl + "sub-url")
if err != nil {
    return
}
```

I've checked and made sure that my service account was loaded correctly. In both cases above, I received `401 "The access token could not be verified"`

Comment: What are the errors returned from the calls to `google.DefaultClient` and `client.Get`?

Comment: There is no error returned from google.DefaultClient (I checked that my service account was loaded correctly). For the `client.Get`, it returns 401 "The access token could not be verified"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while diving deeper into [Google's Oauth Protocol](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) and [OAuth2](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2), I found that the library in Golang does not follow fully google's OAuth2 protocol.

- Flow in Google's spec: Generate and sign JWT in HTTP client (using service account) --> send to google's server --> get a new signed JWT --> use the new token for other requests
- Golang lib: Generate and sign JWT --> use this token for other requests

It's surprising that the Nodejs library handles the flow correctly, whereas the Golang one does not. I summarized my investigation into a [blog post](https://medium.com/@huynvk/handle-authentication-for-cloud-function-client-in-golang-9337b20f9650).

For those who want a short answer, here is my implementation (I moved some parts into a public repo):

```golang
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    "github.com/CodeLinkIO/go-cloudfunction-auth/cloudfunction"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
)

func main() {
    baseUrl := "your-cloudfunction-baseurl"
    ctx := context.Background()
    targetAudience := baseUrl
    credentials, err := google.FindDefaultCredentials(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("cannot get credentials: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    jwtSource, err := cloudfunction.JWTAccessTokenSourceFromJSON(credentials.JSON, targetAudience)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("cannot create jwt source: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    client := cloudfunction.NewClient(jwtSource)
    res, err := client.Get(baseUrl + "/cloudfunction-sub-page")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("cannot fetch result: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("cannot read response: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    println(string(body))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an open source app called [token-generator](https://github.com/guillaumeblaquiere/token-generator). It's in Go, and I generate signed identity token for being able to call private Cloud Run and Cloud Function.

Feel free to use it or to copy the core code that you need for your own app!! We can discuss here or open an issue on GitHub if you prefer.